# Force Word document to be in one language no matter what

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2011

When using Word 2011 for Mac, when I paste an image or create a new line after selecting all text and changing the language, the document will at those places change language.

This is very annoying, so is there a way to **force** Word to only allow one language in the document no matter what happens?

Comment: you can create a macro which selects all document contents and changes it to the desired language. also, you can make a quick access button for it.

Comment: @Znau Is it possible to make a macro, which changes the language while keeping the current selection/caret position? `ActiveDocument.Content.LanguageID = lang`, seems to change the language, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This actually works for me: http://pastebin.com/fGs7tncs

Answer (score 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179596 - go to "Language" section. Simply remove other languages and set default the one you want. However, I think that setting the default language alone will do it.

Comment: @Emestas I normally write in 2 different languages, so I can't remove all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your language in tab Review > language 
then uncheck Detect laguage automatically from the status bar.

Comment: I can't see that option: http://i.imgur.com/rwG5u.png